# Use SQL for iOS app and Webpage at once

Tags: ios, sql, wordpress

I 've been thinking about a project for a Website and an iOS app. I have some domains (Webserver) with SQl. It should become sth. like a News-Blog about a special topic.
So I want to ask, if it would be possible to upload an article into SQl and load it to my app and website.

The problem is, that i've never worked with Sql before and have absolutely no knowledge about Sql. The app would be made in Swift and the Blog(Website) with Wordpress.

So, how should I proceed and where do I have to pay attention?
(Sry for my english, but i hope you understood what I want to do)

SQl = MySQL version 5.5.49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I clearly understood your question but I think that your main concern is to know whether it is possible or not to use a single database to store the data from **BOTH** your mobile app AND your website.

The answer is yes. The database will be the same, the data is simply displayed in two different views (website or mobile app).

Note that SQL will only be used to get or to add some data in the database.
Wordpress uses SQL to store data, and you can use SQL while you develop your mobile app to store or to get data from the database created by Wordpress.

SQL is the language and MySQL is the DBMS (DataBase Management System), these are two different things, as I think that you are confused about this.

Answer (score 1):

you can load data in ios app using REST API.

when you are done with you SQL integration with Wordpress you can use wordpress Web Services plugin for iOS app.

plugin http://v2.wp-api.org/

In iOS app you can use Alamofire Web API Framework to handle Web API request. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire